# How to ignore a token attribute from spirit::Lex when using spirit::qi?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

When I use this qi grammar accepting tokens from Lex:

```
pair %=  token(ID_MARKER)
    >> ':'
    >> atom
    >> ','
    >> atom
    ;
```

in conjunction with this fusion/tuple mapping to assist in the capture:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Client::pair_rec,
    (std::string,      m_dummy  )  // want to rid of this capture of ID_MARKER
    (Client::atom_rec, m_atom_1 )
    (Client::atom_rec, m_atom_2 )
)
```

everything works fine.

*But I would like to use the `ID_MARKER` just for parsing; I don't really need or want to capture it.*

So I tried to ignore the attribute by using `qi::lit`:

```
pair %=  qi::lit( token(ID_MARKER) )
    >> ':'
    >> atom
    >> ','
    >> atom
    ;
```

along with removing `m_dummy` from the capture, but I just get a wall of template errors.

**What should I be doing instead, to clean this up?**

Comment: @llonesmiz +1 thx again - omit works perfectly.  If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without code to test I can't be sure, but:

```
pair %=  qi::omit[ token(ID_MARKER) ]
    >> ':'
    >> atom
    >> ','
    >> atom
    ;
```

should work. You could also add a `token_def<lex::omit> marker;` in your lexer.